# LastActivityDate is NULL

Tags: sharepoint-online

I noticed many sites in SPO has an empty Last Activity Date in SPO admin. Does this mean it has no activity last 180 days?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No, the last activity date would have value although the site has no activity last 180 days. I also have many sites in SPO has an empty Last Activity Date in SPO admin.

It means the site has no activity since you created it. For example, you create the site on 5/27/2020, but since then no users have accessed this site. The last activity date would show empty.

Comment: I have sites with null and file count  larger than 0. Are you sure.

Comment: The same in my end. These files should be system files.